# Polynomial Subspace Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

[Polynomial Subspace Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjRql.png)

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this question. I'm stuck on whether these constraints must allow for the the quadratic to make all quadratics in the subspace or not.
My thoughts are that option C and D are correct but do not know how to confirm this.

Comment: It is not uncommon for beginning students to get scared of using functions and polynomials as vectors instead of arrays.  Note that this is identical in all except flavor to the equivalent question about $\Bbb R^3$ and looking at sets of vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}$ satisfying the respective conditions, there being an obvious isomorphism between the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ given by $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}$.  If you can answer the question for $\Bbb R^3$ then you can for here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C$ is not correct, since we do not have closure under scalar multiplication.  The other three are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Only option C doesn't define a subspace: the constant polynomial $1$ is in the given subset, but $(-1)\cdot1$ is not.